# Web2py load pickled data only once when server starts and use that data in module

Tags: python, web2py, pickle

This is in context of making our own search engine in web2py.

I want to load the pickled index only once and then keep reusing it for every request that comes into my web2py application.
Is there a way to do that in a way that doesn't impact per request performance?

Loading it in model doesn't work because the model is executed on every request.
Similarly doing it in a module also will execute the code in the module on every request.

So I tried to load it in shell.py in gluon module exec_environment definition, and put the following code in it.

```
from gluon import current
fp = open(file_name, "r")
tree = pickle.load(fp)
fp.close()
current.tree = tree
```

And to use the tree, in the module I have written

```
from gluon import current
tree = current.tree
```

But there is no increase in performance and the speed is very slow and same as loading the pickle every time. Normally, the search time of query is very low but here still it is taking too much time.

Am I missing something and what I have done is incorrect or is there a correct and better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

In /modules/search_index.py:

```
fp = open(file_name, "r")
tree = pickle.load(fp)
fp.close()
```

In your app code (i.e., in model or controller):

```
from search_index import tree
[do something with tree]
```